# Xamarin Android Fluid GridLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, staggered-gridview

I am searching for a way to implement a fluid grid to display squares. 
I found the RecyclerView combined with a StaggeredLayoutManager. The problem is that I just found the layout with a fixed column width. But I also want to have a variable row and column height and width. 
What I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Your question is looking for a library, tutorial or some other off-site resource. So I have marked it for closure. Anyways, you could take a look at this: https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view maybe make a binding project for it and give it a spin. It seems to fit your requirements.

Comment: This one could also be a possibility: https://github.com/Comcast/FreeFlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing my own algorithm to insert views into a standard Gridlayout.

Comment: Share it here please